# What's the best approach to handling multiple file uploads in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to attach multiple files to a comment model (currently with a has_many :attachments) using paperclip. It seems to be quite a lot of work and a bit fiddly for something that should be trivial. What's the modern rails way of doing this, with scalability and security taken into account?

Comment: What do you mean by a bit fiddly? I use the same method (using a `has_many` to some sort of resource model which holds the paperclip attachment). You're just creating `:attachment` records for your `:comment`, which is like a `:user` creating a `:comment`. Seems trivial enough to me, but I'll up-vote this because I'd also like to see if there are any alternatives.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://rubygems.org/gems/uploader

Comment: I've used all of it's components before, but I also don't like to rely on Flash to do my uploading for me. I can show you how to handle multiple uploads with Javascript in a very ajaxy-manner, if you like.

Comment: That's appealing- how would you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using [jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload). It's compatible with all browsers and doesn't require any flash or whatever: only javascript.

Look in the wiki, there are tutorials. I made one for v3 and v4, and someone did the one for the latest version.

Comment: i didn't but I won't: I don't want to depend on swf objects.